# MySQL where column = 'x, y, z'

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my situation: I need to select all the messages where user_id = x OR y OR z.

I have an array in PHP:

```
users = ('1', '2', '3')
```

is there anyway to select all the messages where user_id = one of those values without having a massive query of:

```
user_id = '1' OR user_id = '2' OR user_id = '3?'
```

(I need to receive the messages of 100+ people so it would be inefficient)

Thanks

Comment: Note that there is typically no difference in performance between IN and a bunch of OR comparisons.  The ANSI standard defines IN to be the same as = ANY, which is supposed to use the normal = comparison operator in succession (thus following the usual NULL rules).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy to do :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id IN('1','2','3')";
```

Since your value is in array you can use:

```
$users = array('1', '2', '3');
$user_id = "'" . implode("', '", $users ) . "'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id IN($user_id)";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Yes! You can use the `IN` operator:

```sql
user_id IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

If your array will always be safe and contain elements, you can do:

```php
"user_id IN ('" . implode("', '", $users) . "')"
```

in PHP, too.

Answer (score 8):

Use an [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause.

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE user_id IN ('1','2','3')
```

Comment: I'll add because it may not be immediately clear: The contents of the IN clause can be another query. i.e `WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_type = 100)`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't like `IN` keyword. Instead, you can use a regular expression like this:

```
select * from your_table where user_id regexp '1|2|3'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user_id >= 1 AND <= 3
```

Is one alternative.

Comment: The only problem with that is that I would want to select certain numbers so one time it may be: 1,2,4 instead of 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

before strings ids are:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id IN('1','2','3')";
```

preformance int for ids:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id IN(1,2,3)";
```